# Cloud Function with Java and Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-functions

I'm pretty new to this stuff, but I need it for university. So maybe someone can help me please?
I've made a little Java Application with Springboot to handle a simple ToDo-List:

```
package coco.ToDo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class ToDoListController {

    private final ToDoListService toDoListService;

    @Autowired
    public ToDoListController(ToDoListService toDoListService) {
        this.toDoListService = toDoListService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/ToDoList")
    public List<ToDo> getToDoList() {
        return toDoListService.getToDoList();
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/ToDoList/add")
    public void addToDo(@RequestParam("ToDo") String toDo){
        toDoListService.addToDo(toDo);
    }
}
```

I would like to run it on gcloud with Cloud Functions.
But i haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions is designed to handle only a function, only ONE entry point. If you have several entry point (request mapping) you must host a webserver on App Engine or on Cloud Run.